# How to display Current Time only

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I want to display  current time only  but this code displays current date and time both

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/karachi');

$v = time();
$v_as=date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $v);
```

The complete code

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO version_details( assess_day) VALUES (:v_as)";
```

`$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)`;

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/karachi');

$v = time();
$v_as=date("Y-m-d h:i:s", $v);


$v_as=date("h:i:s", $v);




bindParam(':v_as', $v_as, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

but than it displays `000-00-00   00-00-00`

The data type of the v_as is TimeStamp.

Kindly guide me how can this code be changed so only the current time is displayed.

Comment: why don't you use simple `date('h:i:s');`

Comment: i think you got confused in using `now()` in mysql into using it in PHP

Comment: NOW() is mysql function, not php

Comment: I tried date('h:i:s'); but the output is 000-00-00   00-00-00

Comment: @Arshia see my answer it will solve your problem

Comment: I strongly advice you to take a look at Datetime: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/karachi');
echo date('h:i:s');
```

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?

Comment: I feel, You have datatype as datetime change it to time so that you can store the time only

Comment: datatype is TimeStamp

Comment: You have to change it to time only and than run the code.

Comment: Thankyou  now the output is time only after setting the type to time.

Comment: sir kindly answer to my this question also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325828/pagination-display-error-using-mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Instead of now() change it to your variable $v

```
$v_as=date("h:i:s", $v);
echo $v_as;
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/180705)**

Comment: I tried this too but same output, I have edited the code kindly check is it display error?

Comment: @Arshia we all have related answers the problem is not that code but something that you didn't include

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$current_time = date('h:i:s');
echo $current_time;
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/180690)**

**[Demo 2](https://eval.in/180711)**

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?

Answer (score 0):

change karachi 'K' is caps, other wise you get output but its shows default timezone time

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
echo date("h:i:s");
```

**EDIT**: Use below code

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
$sql = "INSERT INTO version_details(assess_day) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$v = time();
$v_as=date("h:i:s", $v);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $v_as);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?

Comment: The output is the same :(

Comment: @Arshia what did you get? what did you want? so samples

Answer (score 0):

$time = date("g:i a");
show current time for more detail look parameter on http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Comment: no i checked it gave me output 9:50 am
echo $time = date("g:i a");

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/karachi');
$current_time = date('h:i:s');
echo $current_time;
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/180702)**

Comment: I have edited the question and posted all code. kindly check what is missing because i have tried all the answers.. Is there any issue in display code ?